Kafkajs `consumer.disconnect()` not resolving
i currently start experimenting with KafkaJS with the following use-case:
I want to retrieve all messages within a given timerange.
So i build a server action which creates a kafka consumer, aggregates all messages so far and filters all out of desired timerange. Pretty pragmatic but just a starting point.
What i don't get is the reason why it doesn't disconnect after reaching the latest offsets.
It consumes the messages properly and after all it stucks infinitely at await consumer.disconnect() (commented) without any error or timeout.
Any ideas whats wrong here?
Context (package.json also below):

nodejs: 22.6.0
Nextjs: 14.2.6
Luxon: ^3.5.0
Kafkajs: ^2.2.4

import { Kafka, EachMessagePayload, KafkaConfig } from 'kafkajs';
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

export interface MessageEnvelop {
    topic: string;
    key: string | null;
    value: string | null;
    timestamp: DateTime;
}

const kafkaConfig = {
    clientId: `my-client`,
    brokers: [process.env.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS!!],
    ssl: {
        // @ts-ignore
        'ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm': 'https'
    },
    sasl: {
        mechanism: 'plain',
        username: process.env.KAFKA_USERNAME!!,
        password: process.env.KAFKA_PASSWORD!!
    }
} satisfies KafkaConfig;

const client = new Kafka(kafkaConfig);
const adminClient = client.admin();

async function getLatestOffsets(topic: string) {
    await adminClient.connect();
    const offsets = await adminClient.fetchTopicOffsets(topic);
    await adminClient.disconnect();
    return offsets;
}

async function resetOffsets(consumerSuffix: string, topic: string) {
    console.log(`Resetting offsets for topic ${topic}`);

    await adminClient.connect();
    await adminClient.resetOffsets({ groupId: 'my-consumer-group', topic, earliest: true })
    await adminClient.disconnect();
}

async function getMessages(consumerSuffix: string, topic: string, fromTime: DateTime, toTime: DateTime, timestampExtractor: (message: string) => string): Promise<MessageEnvelop[]> {
    await resetOffsets(consumerSuffix, topic);

    const consumer = client.consumer({ groupId: 'my-consumer-group' });

    await consumer.connect();
    await consumer.subscribe({ topic, fromBeginning: true });

    const latestOffsets = await getLatestOffsets(topic);
    const messages: MessageEnvelop[] = [];
    const partitionOffsets: { [partition: number]: number } = {};

    latestOffsets.forEach(({ partition, offset }) => {
        partitionOffsets[partition] = parseInt(offset, 10);
    });
    console.log("Partition offsets: ", partitionOffsets);

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
       consumer.run({
            eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }: EachMessagePayload) => {
                console.log(`Received message from topic ${topic} on partition ${partition} with offset ${message.offset}`);
                const messageTimestamp = DateTime.fromISO(timestampExtractor(message.value!!.toString()));

                if (messageTimestamp >= fromTime && messageTimestamp <= toTime) {
                    messages.push({
                        topic: topic,
                        key: message.key?.toString() || null,
                        value: message.value?.toString() || null,
                        timestamp: messageTimestamp
                    });
                }

                if (message.offset === (partitionOffsets[partition]-1).toString()) {
                    partitionOffsets[partition] = -1;
                }

                console.log(`Partition ${partition} has offset ${message.offset} and latest offset is ${partitionOffsets[partition]}`);
                console.log(partitionOffsets);
                if (Object.values(partitionOffsets).every(offset => offset === -1)) {
                    console.log(`consumed ${messages.length} messages. Disconnecting consumer ...`);
                    await consumer.disconnect(); // <---- STUCKS HERE
                    console.log("resolving promise ...");
                    resolve(messages);
                }
            }
        })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error while consuming messages: ", error);
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}

package.json
{
  "name": "zip-debugger",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.13.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
    "@mui/material-nextjs": "^5.16.6",
    "luxon": "^3.5.0",
    "next": "14.2.6",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/luxon": "^3.4.2",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.6",
    "kafkajs": "^2.2.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


Calling .disconnect() will wait for your consumer to get stopped.
Since you are awaiting .disconnect() within your eachMessage function, you are effectively locking yourself forever.
You need to let your eachMessage function return (resolve) then the .disconnect() function can also be resolved.
The most simple solution is to not await consumer.disconnect() in your case. (but make sure to handle the promise in another way)
